# Uncaught promise invalid link when use string page name instead of component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, es6-promise

sending page names from php as string

```
[{component:"HomePage"}]
```

and trying to use it in

```
 openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    console.log(page.component);
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
```

on console i got correct page name but while running

`this.nav.setRoot` generates

uncaught promise invalid link error

Comment: Could you try `this.nav.setRoot({component:"HomePage"})`. Im not sure but i guess the error is advicing you to using this way.  Another suggest: `this.nav.setRoot("HomePage")`

Comment: this.nav.setRoot("HomePage") always generates error of uncaught promise invalid link even if i hardcode the name of page

Comment: and when i use this.nav.setRoot({component:"HomePage"}) it generates error Uncaught promise invalid view to insert

Comment: Could you look at this link: [Ionic 2 setRoot](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot)

Comment: Don't get how to use this

Comment: as per i know both the ways generates errors